# Spring Cloud Config Server with GIT Repo configured is not starting up successfully

Tags: spring-boot, java-11, spring-cloud-config, git-repo

I am building Spring Cloud Config server with Sprint Boot v2.6.12 and Spring Cloud Config Server v3.1.1. Below is the application.yml configuration,

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server  
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: git@github.aus.thenational.com:demo/case_configuration.git
          skip-ssl-validation: true
          default-label: master
          clone-on-start: true
          clone-submodules: true
          force-pull: true
          refresh-rate: 60
          search-paths:
          - case/folder1
          - case/folder2
```

Exception we are getting while server startup is as below,

```
2022-12-21 09:51:10.827  WARN 11524 --- [main] [CID:] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthContributorRegistry' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configServerHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration$ConfigServerActuatorConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'configServerHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'searchPathCompositeEnvironmentRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/CompositeConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'searchPathCompositeEnvironmentRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/DefaultRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'multipleJGitEnvironmentProperties' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentProperties' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140'


***************************

APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************


Description:

The bean 'multipleJGitEnvironmentProperties' could not be injected because it is a JDK dynamic proxy

The bean is of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140' and implements:
        org.springframework.cloud.config.server.support.HttpEnvironmentRepositoryProperties
        org.springframework.cloud.config.server.support.EnvironmentRepositoryProperties
        org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy
        org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised
        org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy

Expected a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentProperties' which implements:


Action:

Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @EnableAsync and/or @EnableCaching.
```

I tried configuring http and https proxy settings along with other GIT configurations. But that didnt work.

Expectation is, config server should be up successfully.

Comment: I faced same issue. Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Tried to solve the issue by configuring spring AOP related configurations in application.yml , but that didnt work too.

Seems like something something to do with libraries versions.

Comment: The core issue to be resolved is, The bean 'multipleJGitEnvironmentProperties' could not be injected because it is a JDK dynamic proxy. The bean is of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140' and implements: org.springframework.cloud.config.server.support.HttpEnvironmentRepositoryProperties

Expected a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentProperties' which implements:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).